# Удаление в таблице null и пустых строк с ошибкой 1175

Tags: mysql

```
delete From billing
Where (payer_email is null or payer_email = '')
and (recipient_email is null or recipient_email = '')
```

Где у меня ошибка? Вот еще один вариантов моего запроса:

```
DELETE  FROM  billing
where payer_email is null or ""
and recipient_email is null or "";
```

Как правильно? Вот условие 
          `payer_email` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
          `recipient_email` VARCHAR(255) NULL,

Comment: google: "mysql 1175" => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что Вы ставите AND между условиями WHERE, то есть запись удалитьcя только тогда, когда оба email'а null или ' ', то есть Вы упускаете вариант, когда только один из email null или ''.

Корректный запрос:

DELETE FROM billing
WHERE (payer_email IS NULL OR recipient_email IS NULL)
OR (payer_email = '' OR recipient_email = '');

Comment: но ведь такой же по сути ответ был дан два с половиной года назад.

Answer (score 1):

При возникающей ошибке  в MySQL Workbench  ->  Error code: 1175 
Мне помогла строка  добавленная в начале запроса:
        SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
Это означает - отключить безопасные обновления.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM billing
WHERE (payer_email IS NULL OR recipient_email IS NULL)
OR (payer_email = '' OR recipient_email = '')
```